# Cannot connect to nginx web server over LAN

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, nginx, raspbian

I cant connect to my Nginx web server when on my LAN, I have tried using both the internal and external IP's. I keep getting told connection refused. By this I mean that if I try to connect via web browser chrome/edge I get a connection refused page,

when attempting to download index.php I get connection refused. Ping requests time out both when inside the network and outside.

The site is definitely up http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/tasty.zapto.org.html.

The site-specific Nginx config is here
http://hastebin.com/sijilidise.nginx

if its of use im running nginx on a raspberry pi

Comment: Please confirm those are the correct URLs that you have entered in the question. They look very suspicious to me.

Comment: Corrected the urls

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/81847/cant-connect-to-nginx-webserver-on-lan

Comment: Yeah 9ne of they're comments redirected me here

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried you hastebin config (minus the fast cgi settings) and it seemed to work without issue for me.